# How to set up the following newsletter

Tags: views, 6, emails

My nodes are broken down by taxonomy, each taxonomy term comes with a different icon, I need to set up a newsletter that sends out a title, teaser and the right icon for each node. What is the easiest way to achieve this? Simplenews? ePublish? Do either of these modules easily integrate with Views so I can output the right fields?

Answer (score 0):

[Newsletter can do what you need.](http://drupal.org/node/1212302) The description on the project page:

Multiple newsletters lists configurable on existing terms
Plain text or HTML out of the box.
Multiple schedules Each newsletter can have more than one schedule, e.g. Daily, Monthly, Weekly, manually or even custom, eg after 10 new posts for this term.
Centralized administration and configuration on a single page.
Users can customize the terms in the list they subscribe to.
Custom template per list.
Statistics (CTR and Open-Rate).
Drupal 7 only.

I'm using it on my site and it works like you've mentioned.